# csc.exe not found error

Tags: visual-studio, web-config

I have installed a fresh copy of windows xp 2002 with SP2, and then VS.net 2008 enterprise edition. I am trying to build a simplest possible web application, and its not compiling giving error csc.exe not found. I googled a lot, and spot the problem in the following section in web.config :

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
      <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
    </compiler>
    <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
      <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
      <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
    </compiler>
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

But if i remove the csharp compiler section , and then compile, it compiles fine with vb compiler section.
And if I change the value from v3.5 to v2.0 in the  of csharp section, then also it compiles fine. But then all my Linq Queries are not recognized by the compiler. But System.Linq and all classes present in it are accessible in the code.
Please help in this weird behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, no one has answered this question.
Luckily, I have solved the issue by luck, by installing the .net 3.5 SP1 .
Everything is working fine as expected.

Comment: Hooray for the long tail. That was my problem, too. Thanks!